# Auto increase decrease text font size in a div box as the box gets resized

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `div` box. I am trying to increase and decrease the font size inside the `div` as the `div` size changed. Increase in `div` dimensions to increase `font` size, decrease in `div` dimensions then decrease the `font` size.

E.g. Base size `300px x 300px`, and font size `1em`. As the user drags it to `400px x 400px` let the font increase automatically in size to `1.5em` in a fixed ratio.

I have no clues how to go about it.
How can I do achieve this? One approach is purely CSS an second to be using Javascript. I think pure CSS would be the best choice.

```css
  #box {
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  }

  #box a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    color: black;
  }
  
  h1 {
     font-family: 'Segoe UI';
     font-weight: normal;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The resize Property</h1>

<div id="box">
  <a>How can I change the size of this text font when the box is resized; auto increase font size, auto decrease font size.</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use just `em` and instead use `%` of the `div` `height`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Can you put that in the answer? I have no idea how to do that.